# Sandy Bridge Power Regression

Tags: 11.10, power-management

Ubuntu 11.10 drives my Sandy-Bridge laptop fan crazy, just 1 week before official release!

I thought it was a beta issue when testing daily builds on a regular basis, but I guess I was wrong...

Is the cause of this power regression tracked down? Will this be fixed after release? Should I even consider updating to 11.10 later on...???

Comment: please add to your questions some details of your hardware - laptop model?  type `sudo lshw` in a terminal and paste the output into your question.

Comment: Close-voter(s): this is an old question!

Answer (score 2):

I installed and configured some applications after installing ubuntu 11.10 to configure power related settings. Though the battery life is not as good as I had managed in Ubuntu 11.04 but it is still not bad after applying these settings. I have managed to cool down the fan. My post is at  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859945.

Answer (score 1):

No it hasn't been resolved, it's sort of on purpose in the interest of stability.  You can read more here

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_mobile_uffda&num=1

Answer (score 1):

There are several sites citing the problems related with the Sandy Bridge of Intel which is fairly new.

You have 2 types of problems: Hardware problems and Kernel problems.

**Kernel Problems**

In the Linux kernel, does not matter what version of Ubuntu or what other distro you use, you will still see the problems with the kernel and power regressions. Of course the latest version have more problems but older versions will still several power related issues.

**Hardware Problems**

Without mentioning EVERY LINK that mentions problems about hardware for the Sandy Bridge you could do a google search just for **Sandy Bridge** and you will see several of them. some of which are:

http://www.phoronix.com - Which mentions power regressions, video problems and cpu problems.

http://hardware.slashdot.org/ - which mentions really big heat problems

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2379241,00.asp#fbid=xZbYR5U-2nn - Mentions some of the hardware problems related to Sandy Bridge. Some of which have been solved.

Basically you discovered one of several problems related to a chipset/cpu/kernel problem.

Sounds horrible I know (Me being an Intel follower) but am hoping that Ivy Bridge will solve this with not only eliminating all video/chipset/cpu problems but adding new technology that guarantees that we will not see this horrible problem.